# WCF Streaming not working at server

Tags: wcf, service, streaming, large-file-upload

I have used WCF service to transfer large files in chunks to the server
for that i have reference this article http://kjellsj.blogspot.com/2007/02/wcf-streaming-upload-files-over-http.html

I have configured my application on IIS on my machine. Its work fine here. It allows upto 64mb file upload. But when we have published the site. It allows only maximum 30Mb file if i try to upload more than that i got error 404 - resource not found.

Here is the binding config i have used.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
<!-- buffer: 64KB; max size: 64MB -->
<binding name="FileTransferServicesBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" 
 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom"  maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="67108864">
 <security mode="None">
 <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
 </security>
</binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Please suggest to me if I am missing anything and if required more code please let me know

Answer (score 0):

On your webserver did you adjust the maximum upload size?

Goto "Request Filtering" for the target app, Open the feature, on the right side choose "Edit Feature Settings", in the dialog select a size larger than 30000000 (the default).

If on your local box you were hosting in Cassini, or your local box had different limits this might occur.